Build active file menu is missing
Trying to configure simple task for building and executing simple single file hello world c++ code. I can do this in my Ubuntu WSL machine:

But I can't do the same in remote SSH machine. There is no c/C++:gcc-9 build active file menu there. Additionally this project has CMake configuration.
Why I don't have menu build active file?

question: why are you using single file build tasks when your project has CMake configuration?

I'll be able to write up an answer probably when I get a response in https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/discussions/12165.

the maintainers need more info to answer this question for your specific context. see https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/discussions/12165#discussioncomment-8989685. please provide that info in the discussion there so we can move this Q&A along.
